# Where is the ‘Save as’ option in PyCharm on Mac?

Tags: python, pycharm, save-as

Sorry if this is a very basic question. I’m learning Python and the task at hand is to try using the terminal to run a python script located on my desktop. I could only find tutorials on windows, where in the PyCharm ‘file’ dropdown menu, there is a ‘save as’ option, allowing you to save the file as a python file to your desktop. On Mac this option is nowhere to be found. I have also tried ‘Export’, however this only allows me to export as a HTML file. Can someone please put me out of my misery. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In PyCharm 2023.1.4 (Community Edition) the Save As option is under the FIle menu